# I'm getting error in com.mysql.jdbc.Driver when catch in ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jsp

this is the code.
and it work to another program.
the error in  String driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.
the program cannot find the class of that.
and i have change myy locashost port to 10000.

```
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String dbName="itdashboard";
String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String userName="root";
String password="";

//code in the below was the method

public boolean createMenu(String nama, String icon){
        String password="";
        String userName="root";
        Connection con=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        AksesJdbc db=new AksesJdbc("itdashboard","", "");
        try{
            String insert="insert into mainmenu (nama,icon) values ("
                    +"'"+nama+"','"+icon+"');";
            db.connect();
            db.executeUpdate(insert);
            db.disconnect();
            return true;
        }

        catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(dataDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have imported the mysql driver into your project. If you don't, download it from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j.

If you use Eclipse:

1. Copy-paste the jar directly into your project (`your project/WebContect/WEB-INF/lib`).
2. Right click on the jar -> `Build Path` -> `Add to Build Path`.

Also you could add a finally block to the code and inside there disconnect from the database.

ex:

```
 try{
            String insert="insert into mainmenu (nama,icon) values ("
                    +"'"+nama+"','"+icon+"');";
            db.connect();
            db.executeUpdate(insert);

            return true;
        }

        catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(dataDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            return false;
        } finally {
            db.disconnect();
        }
```

`finally` it is guaranteed to execute even if an exception is thrown or not.

However, if my suggestion doesn't work, please post the Exception Stack Trace

Comment: I'm happy I could help. If that solved your problem you can accept the answer.